# TCP class using Boost library

Tags: c++11, boost-asio, ubuntu-18.04

I have used the Boost library to create a TCP class with async functions, similar to the samples provided by Boost.
When I read/write to the TCP port, is it necessary to always establish a connection using some asynchronous connect function. Is it possible to Connect once, and then do multiple read/write without closing the tcp socket, at different points of time? (I am aware of the nested calls made between an async read & it's handler to make a continuous read operation.)
My intention is to write a Connect function that opens a TCP connection. Then at some later point of time, I will call a Read function to read from the tcp port, from different functions of my program. Is that possible?? Any code samples would be helpful.

Comment: Of course that's possible. In fact, you cannot perform a read/write operation _before_ you open the connection, so by all means, you should do it (some time) after. The library examples show many examples https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

Comment: In these examples, the async read/write operation is made from the handler function of async_accept. I want to avoid this. I intend to call write from anywhere outside the handler of accept. When I do this I get the error - 'Bad file descriptor'